# MySQL Select Where Not In. How to specify multiple fields

Tags: mysql, join

I am using the following query at the minute

```
SELECT SKU, Country FROM Products WHERE SKU NOT IN (SELECT SKU FROM ProductData)
```

This returns me the SKU and Country from my Products table as long as the SKU is not found in the ProductData table.

What I am struggling to achieve next is the same result but where both the SKU and Country are not found on a row in ProductData.

In the following example, MySKU1 is missing from the ProductData table for France and Germany, but my current query will not return them as MySKU1 exists. So I need to add in a second field somehow.

```
Products TABLE
--------------
MySKU1 UK
MySKU1 France
MySKU1 Germany
MySKU2 UK
MySKU2 France
MySKU2 Germany


ProductData TABLE
--------------
MySKU1 UK
MySKU2 UK
MySKU2 France
MySKU2 Germany
```

I believe I can do this with a join too but I don't fully understand the syntax so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `Country` column to the `IN` expression:

```
SELECT SKU, Country 
FROM Products 
WHERE (SKU, Country) NOT IN (SELECT SKU, Country FROM ProductData)
```

Output:

```
SKU     Country
MySKU1  France
MySKU1  Germany
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pz77mr2JkVaUHPRMmPyoXk/0)

Comment: Thanks so much, I was missing Country from the IN expression on my previous attempt. It's obvious now I've seen it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a LEFT join:

```
SELECT p.SKU, p.Country 
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN ProductData d
on d.SKU = p.SKU and d.Country = p.Country
WHERE d.SKU is null or d.Country is null
```

Results:

```
| SKU    | Country |
| ------ | ------- |
| MySKU1 | France  |
| MySKU1 | Germany |
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have accepted the other answer as it's in the same context as my initial query, although from what I've read the Left Join is actually the better way to do it (although I'm not sure what difference it makes). I will be using this answer (upvoted) to learn more about joins. Thanks again

Comment: No worries if you found a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like that?

```
SELECT p.SKU, p.Country 
FROM Products p
Left outer join ProductData pd on pd.SKU = p.SKU and pd.COUNTRY = p.COUNTRY
WHERE pd.SKU is null
```